# searching dictionary for string and returning other value

Tags: python

Trying to search a dictionary that i created called location_hw_map I want it to be a able to search a string 'testString' for one of the words and when found it will return the location.

for example; using the testString it should print out the value of 'lounge'

My code searches it and finds '123456789', but I can't seem to get it to print 'lounge'!

I'm sure it is a simple solution, but I can't seem to find the answer!

Thx
Matt.

Have put a copy here as well; http://pythonfiddle.com/python-find-string-in-dictionary

```
#map hardware ID to location
location_hw_map = {'285A9282300F1' : 'outside1',
                   '123456789' : 'lounge',
                   '987654321' : 'kitchen'}


testString = "uyrfr-abcdefgh/123456789/foobar"

if any(z in testString for z in location_hw_map):
        print "found" #found the HW ID in testString
        #neither of the below work!!
        #print location_hw_map[testString] #print the location
        #print location_hw_map[z]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `any()` to check if the test string is in the dictionary's keys, loop through the dicitonary's keys:

```
for i in location_hw_map: # Loops through every key in the dictionary
    if i in testString: # If the key is in the test string (if "123456789" is in "uyrfr..."
        print location_hw_map[i] # Print the value of the key
        break # We break out of the loop incase of multiple keys that are in the test string
```

Prints:

```
lounge
```

Comment: Might want to break as well.

Comment: Dictionaries are limited to one value correct? ie. key : value1, what can you use for multiple values for the one key ie. key : value1, value2, value3 ??

Comment: @Matt. You cna make the value a list. `{key1 : [value1, value2, value3]}`

Answer (score 1):

```
# A generator to return key-value pairs from the dict
# whenever the key is in testString.
g = ([k,v] for k,v in location_hw_map.iteritems() if k in testString)

# Grab the first pair.
# k and v will both be None if not found.
k, v = next(g, (None, None))
```